# Trouble with Apache Netbeans Profiler and JFrame

Tags: java, netbeans

## Problem:

Hi there, I had a look around and couldn't find a solution so i have resorted to posting. I am using Apache Netbeans with JDK 12 on a win10 machine.

I have written a piece of code that runs fine normally. However when trying to profile the project, I get an error. After some testing I found that the profiler works fine for all of the profiling configurations except the 'methods' configuration. I also found that the error only occurs when I try to initialize a JFrame object.

## Error Message:

Profiler Agent: Waiting for connection on port 5140, timeout 10 seconds (Protocol version: 18)
Profiler Agent: Established connection with the tool
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.netbeans.lib.profiler.server.ClassLoaderManager to method java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(java.lang.String)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.netbeans.lib.profiler.server.ClassLoaderManager
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Profiler Agent: Local accelerated session

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffa034fc5c5, pid=16856, tid=14104

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (12.0.1+12) (build 12.0.1+12)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (12.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
 Problematic frame:
 V  [jvm.dll+0x5ec5c5]

No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

An error report file with more information is saved as:
 C:\Users\demon\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SignalSimulator\hs_err_pid16856.log

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

Profiler Agent: Initializing...
Profiler Agent: Options: >C:\Program Files\netbeans\profiler\lib,5140,10<
Profiler Agent: Initialized successfully
Profiler Agent: 250 classes cached.
Profiler Agent: 250 classes cached.
Profiler Agent: 250 classes cached.
Profiler Agent: 250 classes cached.
Profiler Agent: 250 classes cached.
Profiler Agent: 250 classes cached.
Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:764)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:711)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)

### at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

### BUILD FAILURE

Total time: 3.208 s
Finished at: 2019-05-26T04:26:25+03:00

### Final Memory: 7M/34M

Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) on project SignalSimulator: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException